# Stopping an unknown process in linux server

Tags: java, linux, spring, jar

I have this command in my deployment process. But I want this process to stop and then restart while deploying in linux server. I checked and found that this is simply a JAVA process, and I can't simply kill JAVA as other nimbus and supervisors are running too.

```
sudo nohup java -Droute=full -jar /opt/artifacts/project/project.jar --spring.config.location=/etc/project/application_full.properties >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

So, how can I stop this process?

Comment: Look for its  PID saying `ps -ef| grep "nohup java"` or similar and then type `kill <pid>`.

Comment: Yes, then i have to write a script to extract it's PID and then kill that because it is an automated process and PID may be different multiple times. I am looking for simpler process. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's two lines of codes, I don't know how much simpler you are looking for XD

Comment: do you know the port number on which it is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your oneliner kill: (I know it's bad, but it should work)

```
ps -ef| grep "name_of_service" | grep -oP "root\s+(\d+)\s" | grep -oP "\d+" | kill
```

ps -ef finds the program line:

```
root      5727     1  0 11:38 ?        00:00:00 grep service
```

Then we use `grep` to remove parts we don't want.

And lastly pass the pid to kill.

ps: replace 'root' for the user you know run the service/pid you are looking for.

Comment: You probably have to say `xargs kill` instead of just `kill`.